# Awaken a task while sleeping

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a task that runs periodically 10 second. I do some picturebox refreshing processes by reading database. What i want is to invoke or awaken the thread and do the refresh operation when i click a button immidiately. In short, i want the refresh task to be driven by not only time but also event together. Is this possible? If yes, how? The code block for the task is shown below.

```
while (true)
{
    // do some refresh operation
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}

void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // invoke or awaken thread
}
```

Comment: not with this while loop - basically with Thread.Sleep you're telling windows - don't schedule that thread in the next 10 seconds. I don't know of a way to get that back. You can decrease the time interval and check a variable inside the loop.

Comment: Use the timer control ! it's built for that. You will even avoid doing multithreading operations, as the tick event will be fired within the UI thread.

Comment: What I don't understand is this: Assume the timer updated the GUI and then after 5 seconds you click the button for another manual update. Should the timer run its own update after another 5 seconds or stop until the next turn?

Comment: Why not have two independent updates, one by the button click and one by the timer? Why do they have to be related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off I'd advise you to drop the `Thread` + `Sleep` + `Invoke` combo for timed operations. It's very ugly. There are timer classes for both WinForms and WPF to do these three things automatically (update the GUI periodically from the dispatcher thread). Check out [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) and [System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx).

Now for your specific question, you could simply define a common method for updating the GUI with what you need and call it both from the timer code and from a button handler.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `AutoResetEvent`:

```
protected AutoResetEvent _threadCycle;
_threadCycle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

when you want to wait do:

```
_threadCycle.WaitOne(delay, false);
```

and when you want to set the event, effectually letting the thread to continue:

```
_threadCycle.Set();
```

BONUS:

when you do `_threadCycle.WaitOne(delay, false);` you will get a return value, `true` or `false`, that you can check to see if the timeout did expire or you are continuing because of the manually set event.

BTW:

that will ONLY work if you are doing your task in an alternate thread.  If you use main thread, you will get stuck with waiting for the timeout completion anyway.  Maybe it will be the best to use @Tudors answer, and get this option only as 'through the thorns' way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a AutoResetEvent for this.

What you do is something like (assuming your AutoResetEvent is called 'signal'):

```
while (true)
{
    signal.WaitOne(10000);
    ...
}
```

And in your button handler, just do:

```
signal.Set();
```